# Почему закрыли вопрос о различии Java / JavaScript?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

[В чем разница между Java и JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1273480/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-java-%d0%b8-javascript)

Данный вопрос является конкретным. На него можно дать точный ответ, в котором, собственно расписать суть отличий.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123309/discussion-on-question-by-guesst-roll------java-ja).

Comment: `java`и `javascript` - это два совершенно разных языка))

Answer (score 1):

Хоть я и голосовал за переоткрытие обозначенного вопроса, но всё же хочу отметить, что при создании неких канонических вопросов, вряд ли стоит писать об этом в самом вопросе. Вообще, из текущего текста вопроса ожидается, что ТС сам же и предоставит достаточно развёрнутый ответ по проблеме. Однако, почему-то этого не произошло. Как следствие, рассчитывать на каноничность ответа не приходится. Ну и никнейм автора наводит на некоторое сомнение в доброте намерений.